# Read .txt from multiple .zip in folder

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a folder (not zipped) containing multiple zip files (no other file type within folder). Each zip has the same type of text files containing different data saved within.

I know how to read in each separately, but I am looking to loop the process without having to type in each zip name. The zipfile archive does not seem to allow wild cards, so I cannot loop using this method. Is it possible to loop the process using glob?

The goal is to get the agency names without extracting all the zipfiles.

Single file read

```
import os  
os.listdir('C:\\NTM\\Test\\')  
['00003_32_332.zip', '00011_273_569.zip', '00012_258_276.zip']  
import glob  
glob.glob('C:\\NTM\\Test\\*.zip')  
['C:\\NTM\\Test\\00003_32_332.zip', 'C:\\NTM\\Test\\00011_273_569.zip', 'C:\\NTM\\Test\\00012_258_276.zip']  
import zipfile  
archive=zipfile.ZipFile('C:\\NTM\\Test\\00011_273_569.zip')  
testagency=archive.open('agency.txt')  
testagency.read()  
'agency_id,agency_name,nVRT,ValleyRide'
```

Update:
Now, that I can loop through the zip files and loop through to get the text file - I cannot print the agency_name from all of the zip files in the folder. My current code only prints the name of the last agency from the text file of the last zip file in the folder. Am I missing some compound statement structure?

> > > def csv_dict_reader(file_obj):
> > >           reader=csv.DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=',')
> > >           for row in reader:
> > >               print(row['agency_name'])
> > >
> > > if **name** == '**main**':
> > >           with archive.open('agency.txt')as f_obj:
> > >               csv_dict_reader(f_obj)

Whatcom Transportation Authority

Comment: `for archive_name in glob.glob('C:\\NTM\\Test\\*.zip') : archive=zipfile.ZipFile(archive_name)`. You know loops right?

Comment: archive_name ! that does it

Comment: Ah, OK, I misunderstood your question. Hence, my answer does not address your problem.

Comment: Do you want to extract all .txt files from all .zip files?

Comment: I'm looking to extract only one text file that is in all the zip files. The text file essentially tells me the name of the agency.   Once I get this down, I'm looking to loop through to find out if there are duplicate agencies.

Answer (score 1):

**Sample Code**

```
import glob
import zipfile

dirName = '/backup/'
zipList = glob.glob(diName+'*.zip')

for zipname in zipList:
  archive = zipfile.ZipFile(zipname)
  fileList = archive.namelist()
  for fileName in fileList:
   if fileName.endswith('.txt'):
     archive.extract(fileName)
  archive.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! I think something is missing from this? It doesn't return an error that I can share with you, but it also doesn't run

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Jean-Francois](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6451573/jean-fran%C3%A7ois-fabre)!

```
for archive_name in glob.glob('C:\\NTM\\Test\\*.zip'):  
    archive=zipfile.ZipFile(archive_name)  
    testagency=archive.open('agency.txt')  
    testagency.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

As I could not comment on Fuji Komalans comment.

Here is the fixed code.

```
import glob
import zipfile

dirName = 'C:/test/'
zipList = glob.glob(dirName + '*.zip')
print(zipList)

for zipname in zipList:
    archive = zipfile.ZipFile(zipname)
    fileList = archive.namelist()
    for fileName in fileList:
        if fileName.endswith('.txt'):
            archive.extract(fileName)
            print(fileName)
    archive.close()
```